# How to set libstdc++ linking to static when other linked library link stdc++ as dynamic?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have libraries that link `stdc++` dynamically. I want to create new shared library with new files, link them and link `libstdc++` statically.

I tried to add `-static-libstdc++` to the compilation but it doesn't work. I checked with `ldd` and my library is still dynamically linked.

How can I do it?

Comment: "[I]t doesn't work" isn't a very good problem description. Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to tell us *how* "it doesn't work".

Comment: It is simply dynamically linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have libraries that link stdc ++ dynamically. I want to create new shared library with new files, link them and link libstdc++ statically.

That is a *really bad idea*(TM). When your binary executes on a system with a different version of `libstdc++.so.6`, you will have symbol collisions (unless you are extremely careful about hiding all relevant symbols inside your shared library), which will likely lead to very hard to debug crashes or other undefined behavior.

> I tried to add -static-libstdc++ to compilation but it doesn't work. I checked with ldd and my library is still dynamically linked.

First, adding `-static-libstdc++` to *compilation* does *nothing*. You need to add to *linking*.

Second, it's unclear what you ran `ldd` on, and whether your library depends on other shared libraries. If it does, `ldd` will show *transitive* dependency on `libstdc++`, which is entirely expected.

To see whether your library *directly* depends on `libstdc++.so.6`, do this:

```
readelf -d yourlib.so | grep 'NEEDED.*libstdc'
```